# Configuring Prettier format tool for WordPress in .prettierrc

Tags: wordpress, prettier

I am trying to use Prettier to format my WordPress project JavaScript / CSS files.

I have installed `prettier` using `npm` and I can execute the formatter correctly. I have also installed `@wordpress/prettier-config` `npm` module to get WordPress style configuration for Prettier.

Package home page at https://developer.wordpress.org/block-editor/packages/packages-prettier-config/ tells that I need to add

```
extends @wordpress/prettier-config
```

to `.prettierrc` file to enable use of WordPress rules.

This line gives error:

```
[error] Invalid configuration file `test.js`: Cannot find module 'extends @wordpress/prettier-config'
```

If I use JSON in `.prettierrc`

```
{
    "extends": "@wordpress/prettier-config"
}
```

I get:

```
[warn] Ignored unknown option { extends: "@wordpress/prettier-config" }.
```

and Prettier simply uses default style.

My question is, how do I configure Prettier to use Wordpress style configuration?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are using `.prettierrc` file written in JSON or `.prettierrc.json` just add:

```json
"@wordpress/prettier-config"
```

without brackets.

Answer (score 2):

I was having the same issue, i'm not sure why the documentation shows that syntax, i'm not sure it's supported by prettier.

Instead name your `.prettierrc` file `.prettierrc.js` and use the below to extend the WordPress config by destructuring theirs into the prettier file.

```js
module.exports = {
    ...require('@wordpress/prettier-config'),
};
```

Also you'll want to make sure you use [WordPress' own version of prettier](https://github.com/Automattic/wp-prettier), so you'll get the parenthesis spacing auto-formatting that WordPress use in their eslint.

```
npm i --save-dev "prettier@npm:wp-prettier@latest"
```

Comment: Without `prettier@npm:wp-prettier@latest` it doesn't appear to work for me, so this seems the correct solution